# What is wrong in this code? Why is it giving this error? How this can be removed?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I implemented this code using Java. It gave me an error saying "`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`"
I'm not sure why? Also, I changed the integer I declared (int op=0;) to double with no change. The program works fine for +,/ and -. But not for *. Why is that so?
Here's the code:

```
class test {
    public static void main(String [] mySpace) {
        double op=0;
        if (mySpace[0].equals("*")) {
             op=Integer.parseInt(mySpace[1])*Integer.parseInt(mySpace[2]);
        }
        System.out.println("Heya! "+ op);
    }
}
```

EDIT: I used these commands in the command prompt:

> javac test.java // For compiling my source file with name test.java
>
> java test * 10 20 //For execution

Comment: Well "mySpace" String array should be the the list of arguments you give when you run the application. Probably the program is called with no arguments at all. You should check if the arguments "mySpace" conatin any values at all.

Comment: dont execute from IDE , execute manuallu by :>> java className parameter

Comment: @Ozil check now my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

That's because `*` is a shell wildcard: it has a special meaning to the shell, which expands it before passing it on to the command (in this case, java).

Since you need a literal `*`, you need to escape it from the shell. The exact way of escaping varies depending on your shell, but you can try:

```
java test "*" 10 20
```

See this code

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {


        if(args[0].equals("*"))
        {
                   System.out.println("true");
                  }
                 else
                  System.out.println("false");

        }
```

}

now when i give the command

```
java Test.java * , it will print false
```

but when i give the command

```
java Test.java "*"  // it will print true
```

Answer (score 5):

If you access `mySpace[0]`, the array must have at least one element; else you'll get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Similarly for `mySpace[1]`.

Therefore use `mySpace.length` to check the actual length of the array before trying to access any of its members. The legal indices range from 0 to `mySpace.length-1`; but you probably know that.

If your question is not about the exception itself, but about why Java didn't receive the command-line arguments you think you passed to it, then as a first step use

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mySpace));
```

to diagnose what Java has actually received.

In particular, `*` has special meaning in many situations related to command-line parsing.

Comment: I passed three arguments corresponding to mySpace[0], mySpace[1], mySpace[2]. The program works fine for +,/ and -. But not for *. Why is that so?

Comment: @Ozil thats because * is a wildcard in command prompt of windows

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass *command line arguments*. Then you can acess them. You are accessing without passing any command line arguments.Then `mySpace.length` will be 0

But you are using `mySpace[0]` with out any element exist

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing anything into your application hence the size of the array `mySpace` is `0`. Try using

```
java test 123
```